# How to efficiently sum each element of vector with matrix getting enlarged matrix

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I would like to achieve the following in an efficient way in numpy. Suppose I have a matrix

```
A = np.asarray([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

and a vector of the following form

```
B = np.asarray([7, 8, 9])
```

What I would like to achieve is the following: Take the first element in `B` and add it to all elements in `A`. Then we take the second element of `B` and so on. At the end I would like to get a matrix of the form `(A.shape[0]*B.shape[0],A.shape[1])`. The result in this case should be (hopefully on typo):

```
np.asarray([[8, 9], [10, 11], [9, 10], [11, 12], [10, 11], [12, 13]])
Out[142]: 
array([[ 8,  9],
       [10, 11],
       [ 9, 10],
       [11, 12],
       [10, 11],
       [12, 13]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add two new axes to `B` to its end and then perform addition, thus leveraging `broadcasting` and finally a reshape for `2D` output such that the number of columns is same as in `A` -

```
In [396]: (A + B[:,None,None]).reshape(-1,A.shape[-1])
Out[396]: 
array([[ 8,  9],
       [10, 11],
       [ 9, 10],
       [11, 12],
       [10, 11],
       [12, 13]])
```

Also, this is basically outer addition, so with the builtin -

```
In [399]: np.add.outer(B,A).reshape(-1,A.shape[-1])
Out[399]: 
array([[ 8,  9],
       [10, 11],
       [ 9, 10],
       [11, 12],
       [10, 11],
       [12, 13]])
```

Comment: small additional question, how can I tweak the code for multiplication (elementwise) instead of addition, i.e. take first element of `B` and multiply it with the whole matrix `A`, then take the second element etc. At the end the shape should be still `(A.shape[0]*B.shape[0],A.shape[1])`

Comment: You can just replace `+` with `*` in the first approach (or in the other answer with `np.tile`). To use `np.add.outer` (if your data is strictly greater than 0), you could also do: `np.exp(np.add.outer(np.log(B), np.log(A))).reshape(...)`, and you can use `.astype(np.int64)` for example if you want to recast as an integer type.

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this with `np.tile`:

```
In [42]: (A + np.tile(B[:, None, None], A.shape)).reshape(
    A.shape[0] * B.shape[0], A.shape[1]
)
Out[42]: 
array([[ 8,  9],
       [10, 11],
       [ 9, 10],
       [11, 12],
       [10, 11],
       [12, 13]])
```